# how to practice good ethics while executing many curl requests in php

Tags: php, loops, curl, wait

I have done a fair amount of reading on this and I am not quite sure what the correct way to go about this is.

I am accessing a websites api that provides information that I am using on my site.  On average I will be making over 400 different API requests which means over 400 curl requests.  What is the proper way to make my code pause for an amount of time then continue.  The site does not limit the amount of hits on so I will not get banned for just pulling all of the stuff at once, but I would not want to be that server when 10,000 people like me do the same thing.  What I am trying to do is pause my code and politely use the service they offer.

What is the best method to pause php execution with resource consumption in mind?

What is the most courteous amount of requests per wait cycle?

What is the most courteous amount of wait per cycle?

With all of these questions I would also like to obtain the information as fast as possible while attempting to stay with in the above questions.

[sample eve central API response](http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=34)

Thank you in advance for your time and patience.

Comment: This is a good question, but it's very subjective. It depends on how much resources the servers have, how many clients there are, how much bandwidth / processing per request, how many simultaneous (vs. queued) requests you'll be making at a time, etc. Without a lot more data there is no answer, although it's very good that you're thinking about such things.

Comment: @Chris  I do not know how much resources are available as I am on a shared host plan with godaddy.  In addition to this, I do not know how much bandwidth / processing request is used.  The response is a small amount of XML perhaps 10 to 15 lines.  There is no way for me to determine how many clients the site has but I have to assume many as it is eve-central.com which is the oldest market data site for the MMO EVE Online.  I understand to give a precise answer you need more information.  But I think a fair answer can be reached with making a few assumptions.

Comment: @Chris I have updated the OP to have a link to a sample response.

Comment: Not really, no. Most bigger hosts employ load-balancing, and I somehow doubt you'd be able to overwhelm them with 400 small requests. If however you want some kind of real-world number, note that internet explorer limits its own use to 10 TCP connections (by default). Perhaps if you make 10 parallel requests at a time this would be "polite". But for all I know 400 simultaneous requests may be peanuts to these people.

Comment: @Chris Ok I used some incorrect terminology.  The requests are not simultaneous, they are consecutive.  In addition, the requests are made from the server as it is a php script.  As a further note it will be run from as a cron job.

Comment: Unless the requests cost a tremendous amount of resources on the server, making 400 consecutive requests without a delay is probably fine. If time isn't really a problem, maybe a 500ms delay would be good enough between connections -- just enough to let a person or two make their requests if the server is super busy. Keep in mind though that the server probably has its own mechanisms for dealing with a high number of users, so unless YOU consider this to be excessive, I say go for it.

Comment: +1 for EVE Online (and being courteous).  :)

Comment: @Chris  Thank you for your discussion on the issue.  It has partially answered the question.  There are two more parts to the question if anybody wants to take a stab at them.  There is a question of which method of pausing a script is the most resource friendly and the best way to implement this.  This is not only a question for my self but for all of the developers out there that care about not only there own resources but others as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a thought: have you asked? If an API has trouble handling a high load, they usually include a limit in their terms. If not, I'd recommend emailing the service provider, explain what you want to do, and ask what they think would be a reasonable load. Though it's quite possible that their servers are quite capable of handling any load you might reasonably want to give it, which is why they don't specify.

If you want to do good by the service provider, don't just guess want they want. Ask, and then you'll know exactly how far you can go without upsetting the people who built the API.

For the actual mechanics of pausing, I'd use the method alex suggested (but has since deleted) of PHP's [usleep](http://php.net/usleep).

Comment: I suppose this is the best way to answer this question.  I have emailed the devs at eve central and will post the response I get here when i get it.